Remove open lines, but keep closed lines
I have developed a convolution with a kernel set that reliably removes singular and protruding white dots when applied 2-3 times to an image of zeros (black) and ones (white):
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from scipy.ndimage import convolve

kernels = [
    np.array([[1, 1, 1], [-4, 1, -4], [-4, -4, -4]]),
    np.array([[-4, -4, 1], [-4, 1, 1], [-4, -4, 1]]),
    np.array([[-4, -4, -4], [-4, 1, -4], [1, 1, 1]]),
    np.array([[1, -4, -4], [1, 1, -4], [1, -4, -4]])
]

image_path = 'path/to/image/file'
with Image.open(image_path) as image:
    
    if image.mode == 'RGBA':
        image = image.convert('RGB')

    image_np = np.array(image)
    mask = np.isin(image_np, [200, 200, 200]).all(axis=-1)
    
    binary_mask = np.zeros(image_np.shape[:2], dtype=int)
    binary_mask[mask] = 1
    
    for kernel in kernels:
        convolution = convolve(binary_mask, kernel, mode='constant')
        binary_mask[(binary_mask == 1) & (convolution >= 1)] = 0

The most important property of the convolution is that it preserves closed lines (e.g. the edge of a rectangle). However, the convolution only removes open lines (i.e. lines with two ends) completely if the convolution is performed half as often as the length of the line.
This is very ineffective for long lines. Can you help me to develop a kernel (set) that removes open 1-pixel-thick lines after a few convolutions, but preserves closed 1-pixel-thick lines?


wrong approach. use connected components analysis as a basis.

You mean this, for example? https://datacarpentry.org/image-processing/08-connected-components.html

I guess? looks right enough. look up morphological opening/closing, if you haven't. perhaps the same idea can be applied to your set of kernels.

If these are 1-pixel thick lines, then it’s like a skeleton. There are many algorithms designed to work with these. Iteratively removing the end points of lines until a single point is left is quite a trivial operation that leaves loops unchanged (the single pixels are trivial to identify).

Had good luck using this for connected component: https://github.com/seung-lab/connected-components-3d
